# How to avoid runts?

Tags: line-breaking, typography, widows-orphans

Sometimes, a paragraph will end in a short word that appears all by itself on the last line. I believe that such words are called *runts* in typography. Other times, a longer word is broken and only one syllable appears on the last line. Is there a way to automatically fix this?

[image: runt word]
[image: runt syllable]

I know how to fix these manually – by adding `~` before the last word and enclosing it in `\mbox{}` – but that is tedious in a long document. Is there a way to penalize LaTeX for making the last line of a paragraph too short?

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/295547

Comment: It is a duplicate of that one, although the only answer there is koma-script specific, in general the answer would be somthing like `\setlength\parfillskip{0pt plus .75\linewidth}` which will penalise anything needing more than 3/4 of the line white space.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, because there the OP's paragraphs are *forced* to end with a runt, which isn't a problem I have.

Comment: Thank you for the command, but it doesn't seem to do much – in the example it changed _“soda-les”_ to _“so-dales”_ (not exactly what I want) and it left the _“enim“_ runt unchanged.

Comment: Ah, but this question *is* a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114940/ , the answer there also adds `\emergencystretch` which solves my problem.